# SSL certutil Trusted Peer vs Trusted CA -t switch difference

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, webserver, self-signed, certutil

I see two common patterns of using -t switch argument for the certutil tool

```
certutil ... -t "CT,c,c"
```

and

```
certutil ... -t "P,,"
```

when taking care of self-signed SSL certificates for web servers.

Can anyone explain the difference between them and when to use one or the other?

[Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/NSS/Reference/NSS_tools_:_certutil) lists possible values for `-t` switch

```
      + p - Valid peer
      + P - Trusted peer (implies p)
      + c - Valid CA
      + T - Trusted CA to issue client certificates (implies
        c)
      + C - Trusted CA to issue server certificates (SSL only)
        (implies c)
      + u - Certificate can be used for authentication or
        signing
      + w - Send warning (use with other attributes to include
        a warning when the certificate is used in that
        context)
```

But I could not find any further explanation.